# What is the difference between programming in C ++ for AMD and Intel

Tags: c++, assembly, cpu

What I mean: for example Unreal Engine 4. Its run good on Intel, but lagging pretty much on AMD (as Editor and also in lot of games).  Is any difference between them in coding?  How can I write highly optimized code for both of them?
Thanks.

Comment: Dear downvoters. While certainly not the greatest question of all times, the question is possibly not as bad as you might think. It could be different usage of SIMD or other subtle and interesting stuff, after all...

Comment: Thanks. So no dark magic here? Just write good C++ code and it must be optimized for both of CPUs families.

Comment: In every larger piece of Software, there is a certain amount of dark magic ;) But I doubt it is the simple code which makes a difference. Rather, some highly sophisticated optimizations using rather new-ish CPU features which are not actually covered by the c++ compiler.

Comment: AFAIK the most critical parts of Unreal Engine are optimized-by-hand assembly (I mean those, which compiler fails to compile optimally enough). And when binaries are delivered, it's always trade-of between Intel and AMD targets, some parts may have even several code variants and switch in runtime according to the current CPU. ... anyway, usually there's not much to do on C++ source level (maybe some rewrite will "hint" better for compiler in particular target mode, but I would expect this to be very rare), it's lot more about tuning compilation options to compiler, and rewriting ASM parts.

Comment: And of course overall data structure design, if (made up example) one CPU has 8 cache lines, and other only 4, and your data are structured in a way that is using about 7-9 different memory locations during loop, the 4-line CPU will have huge runtime penalty then. I'm not sure what are current Intel vs AMD differences, I was in impression it's still about 5-10% performance and feature-wise they are on par of each other, but your question indicates otherwise (unless you think 10% drop in performance is a lot, that's actually not that bad, Intel CPUs at low end are slower than top line by more).

Comment: This question if very broad. The Unreal engine mostly runs on the GPU, and GPU optimisations is a topic that takes whole books on its own. The parts that run on the CPU must be optimised separately for both manufacturers: there are official optimisation manuals and one from Agner Fog, all documented on the x86 tag wiki. If you read just the first pages you'll see that there is no reason to believe that an optimisation for a uArch has to work in another (even of the same manufacturer).

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that example with UE4. But I can give one more - Arma 3. It's runs awful on AMD. 20 - 30 fps in multiplayer when Intel i5 - i7 runs 80 - 90 stable. 
I just cant understand how 8 core 4.5 ghz processor can run worse than i5 4 core processor. I know about difference in caches, also Intel have hyper threading. But so big difference. Usually is GPU is bottleneck, thats why I was so surprised.

Comment: It would help if you gave us the specific processor models. How do they compare in benchmarks? For example, [the first google hit](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/high_end_cpus.html)  rates the best AMD processor at less than 50% performance of the best Intel, and I think that has been the pattern ever past the days of the AMD K6, around 1997.

Comment: This seems extremely unlikely to me. Sure, there are subtle differences when optimizing for AMD vs. Intel chips, and I could pontificate about that at-length in an answer, but I don't think it would help anyone much. (Also: "too broad".) Anyway, none of these differences are going to explain a night-and-day difference in execution speed like what you suggest in the question. That's explained by your AMD test system having an extremely sub-par configuration compared to your Intel test system, which is not an interesting Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @peter Not quite. The Athlon XP was a beast of a chip, running circles around anything that Intel was offering. To be fair, the Pentium 4 that served as its primary competition was a dog, performance-wise, and was often beat in benchmarks by Intel's own top-of-the-line Pentium III, but AMD was doing some *really* impressive things with the Athlon series and continued that into the Athlon XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ALWAYS for optimising any code, the biggest gains are in changing the algorithm to the most efficient one for your data-set. Do this before you do any other performance optimisation.

The second step in improving performance is to figure out what parts of your code stand for the biggest "hit", and concentrate on that. Of course, that becomes a "peeling an onion apart" problem, where, when you improve the performance of one function, you end up with something else being the slowest part...

I'm not going to search out and link to the various performance optimisation pages (documents, etc) available. Both Intel and AMD have optimisation guides, with comments as to what different models of their processors can do what and which code-sequences and such to use (as does for example ARM for their various processor models). All compiler vendors have lists of what options affect code generation in what way (e.g. enabling SSE, AVX, etc). Different compilers are more or less good at actually USING "new" instructions available in the latest versions of processors.

Optimising code for one processor subarchitecture [the difference between processors within for example x86, ARM, etc] is not terribly hard. Writing code for multiple processor subarchitectures gets quite hard, especially if you want to squeeze that last little bit of performance out of the processor, because the tricks you have to use are specific to each subarchitecture. There are a few classes of problems:

1. Different features available in different processors, require code to be compiled with the right code-generation options enabled (e.g. SSE, AVX, etc). So, you need to "split" the code into generic code and code that can make use of vector instructions, and either make the compiler vectorise it, or hand-write assembler to make best use of the instructions.
2. Minor archetectural differences make different instruction sequences more or less good. So on a Processor X, you should use instructions A, B and C to replace instruction M (because M is unusually slow), but on processor Y, the one instruction M is faster than A, B and C. So again, you have to pick which one you make it fast for - or compile the same code multiple times.
3. Caches are different in different architectures, meaning that optimisation to make something like "copy this data" fast on one architecture may not show the same improvement on another architecture.

Beyond that, you really need to ask a more specific question to some specific code that you know is slow.